# How to improve smartcase in Vim?

Tags: vim

With below options enabled in `.vimrc`:

```
set ignorecase
set smartcase
```

When no capital letter is included in the search pattern, the search is case-insensitive (`abc` will match `Abc`, `AbC`, `ABC`, etc).

When at least one capital letter is included in the search pattern, the search becomes case-sensitive for the whole pattern (`Abc` will match `Abc`, but will *not* match `AbC`).

What I would like is enabling case-sensitivity only for the individual letters provided as capitals in the search string (`Abc` to match `AbC`, `ABc`, `ABC`, etc). Can this be achieved?

Comment: No, this can't be achieved with built-in options.

Comment: Thanks, @romainl. At least now I know that having this functionality is not possible without raising a feature request. Hopefully, this is also achievable through a custom vim command.